# ArcGIS Pro ERROR 999999 using multidimensional data

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, error-999999

I am working with a multidimensional raster dataset having ~15000 days of temperature data. I am trying to use multidimensional tools such as anomaly but I keep having the same error:
[image: This error]

> ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail.

I tried to clip the raster dataset to a very small area just to see if my pc fails to handle big data but the result is the same.

Is there anyone having the same issue?

Do these multidimensional tools even work?

I am running it on a Ryzen 5 5600 with 16GB RAM and 4GB GPU machine. The ArcGIS Pro version is 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, so i tried using the same tools from raster functions and it worked. i also tried to clip my data to smaller area and that method worked as well. Try using generate trend raster from raster functions

Comment: This is not a suitable answer rather a comment. Kindly post it as a comment.

Comment: The answer i have posted is actually a solution, Its a workaround but still i spent hours trying to solve that and came up with it and i need 50 reputations to post a comment, i have not reached there yet. Thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

ESRI employee working on this tool here. This is likely data specific and I want to know more about this bug.

You need to report the bug on https://my.esri.com so we can debug and fix the problem

Or send me your email so I can set you up with a way to transfer the reproducible case.

There is no way anyone can help otherwise.